# loopback rest api framework for below android 4.3

Tags: android, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

Can we use loopback rest api for android development below android api 18 ? 
 Is there any support framework for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The api to use has nothing to do with the SDK version. It's basically a bunch of URLs you call, and responses you get. So nothing to do with which version of android api you are using :)